# Is there any specific way to convert the LiveData to ArrayList without using the observer inside the repository while using MVVM with DI in android

Tags: android, mvvm, dependency-injection, android-room, android-livedata

So here is my problem statement

**

- What I am doing

**
I am using MVVM with dependency injection in my android application, therefore, I have the repository, in which I am basically fetching the data from firebase and returning the live data to the repository, but now I just integrated the room database to my project and here the actual problem comes,

**

- what i wanted to achieve

**
I want to store the data that is coming from the server into the local room database and as the MVVM suggest as a design pattern, I need to this task inside the repository

**

- Here is the problem lies

** 
The data coming to the repository form the firebase class is live data and i need to store this data to room database but i don't know how to convert the live data into the ArrayList of data to store the data into the room using DAO class 
i know some of you will say that set an observer to observe the data into the repository but mind this point that i am not passing the context to the repository

**

- Repository code

**

```
package com.baymax.quotesapplication.data

import android.os.AsyncTask
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import com.baymax.quotesapplication.data.db.QuoteDao
import com.baymax.quotesapplication.data.db.QuotesDatabase
import com.baymax.quotesapplication.data.db.entity.Quote

class QuoteRepository private constructor(private val firestoreSource: FirestoreSource,
                                          private val database: QuotesDatabase,
                                          private val status:String){

    fun addQuotes(quote:Quote)
    {
        InsertNoteAsyncTask(
            database.getQuoteDao()
        ).execute(quote)
        firestoreSource.addQuotes(quote)
    }

    fun getQuotes():LiveData<List<Quote>>
    {
        if(status.equals("ONLINE"))
        {
            return firestoreSource.getQuotes()
        }
        return database.getQuoteDao().getQuotes()
    }

    fun deleteAllNotes() {
        DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(
            database.getQuoteDao()
        ).execute()
    }

    companion object {
        // Singleton instantiation you already know and love
        @Volatile private var instance: QuoteRepository? = null

        fun getInstance(firestoreSource: FirestoreSource,database: QuotesDatabase,status: String) =
            instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: QuoteRepository(firestoreSource,database,status).also { instance = it }
            }
    }

    private class InsertNoteAsyncTask(val quoteDao: QuoteDao) : AsyncTask<Quote, Unit, Unit>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg quote: Quote?) {
            quoteDao.addQuote(quote[0]!!)
        }
    }


    private class DeleteAllNotesAsyncTask(val quoteDao: QuoteDao) : AsyncTask<Unit, Unit, Unit>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Unit?) {
            quoteDao.deleteAllNotes()
        }
    }
}
```

**FirebaseSource**

```
class FirestoreSource (){

    private val firestore:FirebaseFirestore by lazy {
        FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    }

    private val quoteList = mutableListOf<Quote>()
    private val quotes = MutableLiveData<List<Quote>>()

    init {
        quotes.value = quoteList
    }

    fun addQuotes(quote:Quote)
    {
        val map:HashMap<String,String> = HashMap<String,String>()
        map.put("Quote",quote.quote)
        map.put("Author",quote.author)
        firestore.collection("Quotes").add(map as Map<String, Any>).addOnCompleteListener {
            quoteList.add(quote)
            quotes.value = quoteList
        }
    }

    fun getQuotes(): LiveData<List<Quote>>
    {
        firestore.collection("Quotes").get().addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful)
            {
                quoteList.clear()
                for (quote in task.result!!)
                {
                    quoteList.add(Quote(quote.get("Quote").toString(),quote.get("Author").toString()))
                }
                Log.d("EVENT","Live Data is updated")
            }
        }
        quotes.value = quoteList
        return quotes
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve that by using `Transformations.switchMap()`

FireStore:

```
class FirestoreSource {
    fun getQuotes(): LiveData<List<Quote>> {
        // fetch data here and return live data
    }
}
```

QuotesDatabase:

```
class QuotesDatabase {

    fun saveQuotesInDb(quotes: List<Quote>) {
        // save in db here
    }

    fun getQuotes(): LiveData<List<Quote>> {
        return dao.getQuotes()
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
class Repository(
    private val firestoreSource: FirestoreSource,
    private val database: QuotesDatabase
) {
    fun getQuotes(): LiveData<List<Quote>> {
        return Transformations.switchMap(firestoreSource.getQuotes()) {
            database.saveQuotesInDb(it)
            database.getQuotes()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Sianaki, you are close to the solution, but i am facing a problem with your code that is The Transformations.switchMap will be triggered only if the data from firestoreSource.getQuotes() changes, but one thing you are forgetting is that the data is Asynchronous, so in the begining the data is null and that is going to be stored in the database and returned to ViewModel to observe, now after the data get loaded from firebase the Transformations.switchMap is not getting triggered that resutls in not storing and displaying the data

Comment: @SaquibSiddique As I commented in my code, fetch data from the network and wrap it by LiveData, so at first livedata contains an empty list, when data received from the network set it as value of livedata which will trigger switchMap

Comment: yes, i am doing that only, still the Transformation.switchMap is not getting triggered even after the fetchig of the data from firebase, please have a look upon the FirebaseSource class, that i just added

Comment: @SaquibSiddique Move `quotes.value = quoteList` to `addOnCompleteListener` callback

Comment: Hurray, it's working now, You are trurely amazing man, thank you so much

Comment: @SaquibSiddique You are welcome.when an answer works for you mark it as solution:)